# Static files in Django 1.6

Tags: django, django-staticfiles

I'm probably doing multiple things wrong here because I still can't get static files to work correctly in my development environment despite closely following the tutorial. I have a feeling it's because it works slightly differently in Django 1.6, and I can only find answers for previous versions.

Here's my directory structure:

```
mysite
├───app1
├───mysite
│   └───templates
├───resources
├───static
│   ├───css
│   ├───fonts
│   └───js
└───app2
```

My installed apps, to prove I have staticfiles on:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'app1',
    'app2',
)
```

My template and static file settings:

```
 # Templates
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "mysite/templates"),
)

# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

I even did this in my `urls.py` as suggested:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    ...
) + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

And finally, my request:

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<link href="{% static "css/core.css" %}" rel="stylesheet">
```

If I navigate directly to `http://127.0.0.1/static/css/core.css`, I get `'css\core.css' could not be found`

Please tell me what I did wrong =[

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since the static directory does not "live" in one of the apps (`app1`, `app2` in your case), django can't find the static directory. So with your current structure you need to add the static directory to the `STATICFILES_DIRS`.

From the documentation:

> "Your project will probably also have static assets that aren’t tied to a particular app. In addition to using a static/ directory inside your apps, you can define a list of directories (STATICFILES_DIRS) in your settings file where Django will also look for static files."

Something like this:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
)
```

See:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-STATICFILES_DIRS

Hope this helps.

Comment: I thought this worked at first because it showed a blank page, but then I realised it was just because the server wasn't online. Still gives the same problem!

Comment: Can you print out the contents of the STATICFILES_DIRS ? I mean somewhere after configuration.

Comment: ('D:\\Users\\Chris\\Documents\\GitHub\\mysite\\mysite\\static',)

Comment: Okay, now is the path correct ? Does it resolve to the static directory which you have provided in your tree structure ? Oh, and just to clarify you are running with `DEBUG = True` setting right ?

Comment: No =) There shouldn't have been two 'mysites' in there. Should have been just `os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),`

Comment: I was stuck with the same problem for ages, and I think the most crucial thing to realise is that `staticfiles` doesn't look for files in `STATIC_ROOT` *at all*. `STATIC_ROOT` *only* defines the directory where everything will be copied or sym-linked to when you run `collectstatic` (even though it clearly says so in the docs, I kept on missing that fact). Hope that helps someone...