# Unable to serve static files with Django runserver

Tags: python, django, static, django-staticfiles

I have this configuration in my settings.py file

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'corsheaders',
    'dashboard',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)

TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
    'django.core.context_processors.debug',
    'django.core.context_processors.i18n',
    'django.core.context_processors.media',
    'django.core.context_processors.static',
    'django.core.context_processors.tz',
    'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
    'django.core.context_processors.request',
    'social.apps.django_app.context_processors.backends',
    'social.apps.django_app.context_processors.login_redirect',
)

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATIC_ROOT = '/home/workspace/app-toscana/django/djangoapptoscana/djangoapptoscana/static'
```

My Django project is located in the following directory:
`/home/workspace/app-toscana/django/djangoapptoscana`

Inside this directory the project structure is the following one

```
.
├── dashboard
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── admin.pyc
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __init__.pyc
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── models.pyc
│   ├── templates
│   │   ├── index.html
│   │   ├── loginpage.html
│   │   ├── registerpage.html
│   │   └── startpage.html
│   ├── tests.py
│   ├── views.py
│   └── views.pyc
├── djangoapptoscana
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __init__.pyc
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── settings.pyc
│   ├── static
│   │   └── admin
│   │       ├── css
│   │       │   ├── ...
│   │       ├── img
│   │       │   ├── ...
│   │       └── js
│   │           ├── ...
│   │   └── bootstrap
│   │       ├── css
│   │       │   ├── bootstrap.css
│   │   └── ....
│   ├── urls.py
│   ├── urls.pyc
│   ├── wsgi.py
│   └── wsgi.pyc
└── manage.py
```

Here it is a code snapshot of my **dashboard/template/index.html**

```
{% load staticfiles %}
...
<link href="{% static 'bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css' %}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
...
```

When I try to test the project using `python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000` I'm not able to serve static files receiving **404 error**.
*I'm running Django 1.6.1 version*.
Any suggestion? Thanks!

Comment: Try pointing your link to: {% static 'admin/css/bootstrap.css' %}

Comment: Nothing! Take a look at the edited tree: bootstrap directory is already the proper path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try specifying `STATICFILES_DIRS` in `settings.py` file.

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = '/home/workspace/app-toscana/django/djangoapptoscana/djangoapptoscana/static'
```

`STATIC_ROOT` is the absolute path to the directory where `./manage.py collectstatic` will collect static files for deployment. Create `static_cdn` folder at the following path.

```
STATIC_ROOT = '/home/workspace/app-toscana/django/static_cdn'
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19891454/static-files-in-django-1-6) stack overflow link and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8687927/django-static-static-url-static-root) one should help you.

Comment: Thanks! I forgot the STATICFILES_DIRS